# one function out of two with integrals

Tags: functions, continuity

I'm looking to have a single function $f(x)$ that is drawn from and satisfies two base functions

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (f(x)) \, dx = 1$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x(f(x)) \, dx = 0$$

I'm sure there's some shortcut to it, an obvious function given the outstanding $x$ in function two that makes it zero and the other $1$. I just don't see it. I'm sure someone here will get it instantly but I'm deaf and dumb right now.

Answer (score 1):

Any probability density $f$ that is symmetric about $0$ works provided the integral of $|x|f(x)\,dx$ is finite.  For example
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac 1 2 & \text{if } -1<x<1, \\[10pt] 0 & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}
$$
This is the uniform distribution on the interval $[-1,1]$.

Or you can use the standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any symmetric function $f(x)$ for which both integrals are defined. If the first integral is not equal to $1$ just divide $f(x)$ by a constant to ensure it is. Then $xf(x)$ is an antisymmetric function, so its integral is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Dirac delta $\delta(x-a)$ satisfies the properties you're asking. It is defined as 
$$\delta(x-a)=\begin{cases} \infty & x=a\\ 0 & x\neq a \end{cases}$$
And it satisfy
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \delta(x-a) \mathrm{d}x=f(a)$$
So
$$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)\mathrm{d}x=1$$
$$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\delta(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$$
It's not a function though. It's a distribution :(